# Program for Ubuntu to detect cat-like typing?

Tags: keyboard, cat

A feline hacker has invaded my home. She frequently crawls across and sits on the keyboard, causing all sorts of mayhem. I have gotten into the habit of locking my computer when I step away for a minute but I can't lock it every time she mashes the keys while I'm present.

I have tried non-technical approaches such as locking the door (leading to constant mewing), shooing her away (which makes the keyboard all the more enticing), and moving farther from the desk to make it less accessible (she can jump pretty far). I have not had much success with any of these approaches. Thus I am looking for a technological solution.

[PawSense](https://bitboost.com/pawsense/) (no affiliation) is a Windows program that can detect "cat-like typing". Is there a similar program for Ubuntu?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382535/keyboard-set-to-cat-mode

Comment: @DKBose Interesting and very similar but not quite a duplicate. I am asking for an automatic solution like PawSense rather than locking or manually switching to "cat mode". Also that question links to this similar one: https://superuser.com/questions/27847/how-to-protect-a-keyboard-from-a-cat.

Comment: I didn't state it was a duplicate or even quite a duplicate :D

Comment: My problem is that my cat not goes for keyboard so much, but likes to curl up and sleep on one of my arms. You try to press two keys far apart with one hand.

Comment: You should buy your cat her [own computer](https://www.geschenkidee.de/cattop-laptop-kratzbaum-fur-die-katz.html).

Comment: http://thisiswhyimbroke.com/heated-keyboard-cat-bed

Answer (score 2):

None found.

A search of the links above, plus a web search, and a visit to https://alternativeto.net/platform/linux/ shows no Linux equivalent for PawSense, and its [web page](https://www.bitboost.com/pawsense/) is very specific that Windows is required to run it.

However, you could use [Kittydar](https://girliemac.com/blog/2015/12/25/kittycam-raspberrypi-camera-cat-face-recog-nodejs/) or [similar systems](https://www.hackster.io/windowsiot/cat-door-with-pet-recognition-514dac) to watch for your cat and turn off the power lead to your keyboard when detected, but more hardware would be required.